# how to store list of fragments using SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I'm using SharedPreferences to store a list of fragments of my android, however it gave me thousands lines of error which make non-sense:

2021-12-07 17:09:13.228 14833-14833/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245)
at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:1058)
at .......

(just small parts of error messages)
I tried to store a list of strings it works fine, but if I switch to an object with list of fragments it fails.

Here is my object.java:

```
public class CardList {
    ArrayList<Card> list;  //Card is my fragments
    public CardList(ArrayList<Card> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
    public void updateList(Card c) {
        list.add(c);
    }

    public int getListSize() {
        return list.size();
    }


}
```

here is my MainActivity.java, the new intent here was just to test if I can get my data back when I'm back to MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String WEATHER_PREFS = "weatherPrefs";
    public CardList cardList;
    public ArrayList<Card> cards;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       
        cards = new ArrayList<>();
        cardList = new CardList(cards);

        SharedPreferences setting = getSharedPreferences(WEATHER_PREFS,MODE_PRIVATE);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String savedList = setting.getString("cardList","");

        if (!savedList.equals("")) {
            cardList = gson.fromJson(savedList,CardList.class);
        }


        Button btn= findViewById(R.id.switchActtivity);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                Gson gson = new Gson();

                String savedInstanceString = gson.toJson(cardList);
                SharedPreferences setting = getSharedPreferences(WEATHER_PREFS,MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = setting.edit();
                editor.putString("cardList",savedInstanceString);
                editor.apply();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        Button increase = findViewById(R.id.increase);
        increase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cardList.updateList(Card.newInstance("hello","world"));
                Log.i("Array List Size After Click",String.valueOf(cardList.getListSize()));
            }
        });


    }
    
}
```

Can someone teach me how to store custom object with an arraylist attribute in Android? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Fragment`s aren't `serializable`, meaning they can't be broken down into pure data ie `JSON`, much less `deserializable`.

Looking at your code there is no good way to just make it work either.

You need to follow separation of concerns, `Fragment`s are glorified views. They shouldn't be holding information to any great extent, so they shouldn't be passed around as if they did.

What you could do is have a `CardModel` that contains all information needed for a `Card` `Fragment`.

The `CardModel` can contain simple data that you would find in `JSON` like `Integer`,`String`, etc...

A `List<CardModel>` can be `deserialized` from `JSON`. And then when you're in the `MainActivity` you could create as many `Card` `Fragment`s as needed to represent the `List<CardModel>` with a simple `list.size()`